# Flutter : Custom Painter draw path with different fill and stroke color

Tags: flutter, custom-painting

I am using the CustomPainter to draw a line chart where the line(stroke) needs to be of a different color and the fill color should be a different shade of it.
I could draw the chart but both with same colors.
However, I need the colors to be different.
How can I do this with a CustomPainter?

Also, I want to know how to have a single path painted with different colors instead of a single color if possible.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: can you post the sample code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally draw the stroke with "drawLine" calls and the fill with "drawPath".

You can define 2 different paints and use paint1 with "drawLine" and paint2 with "drawPath".

Comment: I was thinking of using the same but wondered if there is a better way I don't know of.
Also, How can I add gradient color to the drawn path? I'm looking for a simpler solution for the shader asks for a Rect object.

Comment: @AkashGorai to make a Gradient you can create Paint like this: final paint = Paint()
  ..shader = RadialGradient(
    colors: [
      color1,
      color2,
    ],
  ).createShader(Rect.fromCircle(
    center: offset,
    radius: radius,
  ));

Comment: @AkashGorai I do not think there is a way; if you only need a Rect, I think that if you draw 2 rectangles overlapped, one with stroke paint and another with fill paint, you should get it because the fill draws only internally excluding the border.

Comment: I'll try and get back. Thank you for responding :)

Comment: I tried and.. i think I facing trouble with the fill color. I'm using canvas.drawPath() but when style is fill, my chart is filling for the last three coordinates lol. Can you help?

Comment: @AkashGorai I think the problem is that the stroked one must not be over the closed path. You must draw the edge before calling yourPath.close().

Comment: @AkashGorai And you must use a different `Paint` object.

Comment: what if i have more than 2 paints

Answer (score 2):

You have to use 2 times drawPath to set color to stroke and fill

```
    final Paint paint = Paint()
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..color = const Color(0xff0056eb)
      ..strokeWidth = 1.0;

    touchCanvas.drawPath(
      paths[index]
          .transform(matrix4.storage)
          .shift(Offset(offsetX, offsetY)),
      paint,
      onTapDown: (details) {
        onPressed(paths[index], stringPaths[index]);
      },
    );

    final Paint paint2 = Paint()
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill
      ..color =  Color(0xff0056eb).withOpacity(0.05)
      ..strokeWidth = 1.0;
    touchCanvas.drawPath(
      paths[index]
          .transform(matrix4.storage)
          .shift(Offset(offsetX, offsetY)),
      paint2,
      onTapDown: (details) {
        onPressed(paths[index], stringPaths[index]);
      },
    );
```